# How to solve java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.widget.AbsListView.isItemChecked

Tags: android, android-framework

I'm compiling an Android project against API Level 11 (3.0) and I have this code:

```
if (parent instanceof AbsListView) {
    checked = ((AbsListView)parent).isItemChecked(position);
}
```

When I run this in pre-3.0 (lower than API Level 11) devices, I get this error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.widget.AbsListView.isItemChecked
```

In [AbsListView documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#isItemChecked%28int%29), `isItemChecked` is stated as having API Level 1 compatibility, then why do I get the error?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apparently this is what happens:

Since API Level 1, Android framework has already `isItemChecked` on `ListView`.

However, on the release of API Level 11, Google moved the definition of `isItemChecked` to `AbsListView`, which is the superclass of `ListView`. This change doesn't prevent existing code (meant for compiling against pre-API Level 11) to compile against API Level 11, but the generated .class file actually looks for `isItemChecked` on `AbsListView`, which does not exist on pre-API Level 11 devices.

On the [API Differences Report](http://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/11/changes/android.widget.ListView.html), it is stated:

> `boolean isItemChecked(int)`   Method was locally defined, but is now inherited from `AbsListView`.

This is a dangerous pitfall, because the compatibility can't be checked on compile-time at all. You must remember to cast it as `ListView` and not `AbsListView`. Maybe we should avoid `AbsListView` altogther.

Comment: AbsListView documentation should be fixed. It was certainly not added in API 1. Same goes for `AbsListView.setAdaper` but they updated it.